# Full-text search not working as expected for files in shared drives

Tags: google-drive-api, full-text-search

I'm using the Google Drive API to search for files containing specific text in personal and shared drives. My query works fine when searching across both personal and shared drives, but fails to return results when I specify only a shared drive. I'm using the Google Drive v3 API. I have noticed this issue across file types namely, Google Docs, PDF, and DOCX.

I have a PDF file with the text 'Supreme Court' in a shared drive.

I used the following query which searches across personal drive folder (`1gMnP7mt-WQ3qEm8ldi0fSz_jPrQniZSL`) and shared drive (`0AKlb0zenjwlyUk9PVA`). This returns the file:

```
fullText contains 'Supreme Court' and ('1gMnP7mt-WQ3qEm8ldi0fSz_jPrQniZSL' in parents or '0AKlb0zenjwlyUk9PVA' in parents) and trashed = false
```

```bash
curl --location 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=fullText%20contains%20%27Supreme%20Court%27%20and%20(%271gMnP7mt-WQ3qEm8ldi0fSz_jPrQniZSL%27%20in%20parents%20or%20%270AKlb0zenjwlyUk9PVA%27%20in%20parents)%20and%20trashed%20%3D%20false&fields=nextPageToken%2Cfiles(id%2Cname%2Cparents)&spaces=drive&supportsAllDrives=true&includeItemsFromAllDrives=true' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>'
```

However, when I modify the query to search only in the shared drive:

```
fullText contains 'Supreme Court' and ('0AKlb0zenjwlyUk9PVA' in parents) and trashed = false
```

```bash
curl --location 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=fullText%20contains%20%27Supreme%20Court%27%20and%20(%270AKlb0zenjwlyUk9PVA%27%20in%20parents)%20and%20trashed%20%3D%20false&fields=nextPageToken%2Cfiles(id%2Cname%2Cparents)&spaces=drive&supportsAllDrives=true&includeItemsFromAllDrives=true' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>'
```

It returns zero results, which is not what I expected.

Has anyone encountered similar issues or can offer some guidance?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

If `0AKlb0zenjwlyUk9PVA` of `'0AKlb0zenjwlyUk9PVA' in parents` is the drive ID (the root folder ID of the shared Drive), how about the following query parameter?

```
corpora=drive&
driveId=0AKlb0zenjwlyUk9PVA&
includeItemsFromAllDrives=true&
q=fullText contains 'Supreme Court' and trashed = false&
supportsAllDrives=true
```

When this query parameter is used to your showing curl command, how about the following modification?

```bash
curl --location 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?corpora=drive&driveId=0AKlb0zenjwlyUk9PVA&includeItemsFromAllDrives=true&q=fullText%20contains%20%27Supreme%20Court%27%20and%20trashed%20%3D%20false&supportsAllDrives=true' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>'
```

#### Reference:

- [Method: files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/list)
- [Search query terms and operators](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/ref-search-terms)

  > The contains operator matches on an exact alphanumeric phrase if it's surrounded by double quotes. For example, if the fullText of a document contains the string `"Hello there world"`, then the query fullText contains `'"Hello there"'` returns a result, but the query fullText contains `'"Hello world"'` doesn't. Furthermore, since the search is alphanumeric, if the full text of a document contains the string `"Hello_world"`, then the query fullText contains `'"Hello world"'` returns a result.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. Your solution works, but I am not sure how to use this approach to search across multiple shared drives. When I try to search across multiple shared drive folders (`corpora= allDrives`) `0AEyOR4LSWWkHUk9PVA` and `0AKlb0zenjwlyUk9PVA`, the search works whereas the same search on a single shared drive doesn't return the desired result.

Comment: @Yashasvi Galav Thank you for replying. From `Your solution works`, I confirmed that your question was resolved. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't notice about `but I am not sure how to use this approach to search across multiple shared drives.` from your question. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: @Yashasvi Galav About `but I am not sure how to use this approach to search across multiple shared drives.`, in the current stage, if you want to search the files only on multiple shared drives, I think that there are following 2 patterns. 1. Use "Method: files.list" for each shared drive. In this case, my proposed search query can be directly used.

Comment: @Yashasvi Galav 2. After all file lists are retrieved `corpora=allDrives` and `q=fullText contains 'Supreme Court' and trashed = false`, retrieve only the files in the shared drives using a script. If those patterns are not useful for your situation, I apologize again.

Comment: @Yashasvi Galav Although I have been looking for a direct solution to your additional request, unfortunately, it seems that there is no search query for searching files from only multiple shared drives by one API call. I apologize for this. So, as the current workaround, how about the above 2 patterns? If those were not included in your expected result, I apologize.